# MySQL Workbench connection to a MySQL server running in a Google Cloud VM instance

Tags: mysql, google-compute-engine

I have a google cloud vm instance running a Ubuntu OS and I have installed a mysql server there. The server is running and I can check the status by `sudo service mysql status`

I have modified the mysql my.cnf file as,

```
[mysql]
bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

I have setup the firewall of my instance as follows,

```
IP                  Protocol
*******************************************
127.0.0.1/32        all
0.0.0.0/32          all
10.128.0.0/9        tcp, udp, icmp
0.0.0.0/0           tcp:22,3389,443,80 icmp
```

[Click here for the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72NmS.png)

Now in the Mysql connection settings, I have filled up the following,

```
Connection Method: Standard TCP/IP over SSH
Parameter:
SSH Hostname: <vm external ip>:22
SSH Username: <vm username>
SSH Key File: <vm private key file>
MySQL Hostname: 127.0.0.1
MySQL Server Port: 3306
Username: <mysql username>
Password: <mysql password>
```

[Click here for the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0lVd.jpg)

```
But the test connection is giving the error,
Access denied for 'none'. Authentication that can continue: publickey
```

[Click here for the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1iyU.png)

Now, I have created a public key-private key pair by puttygen and successfully established the Winscp connection by that.

Comment: You should not configure `bind-address` to `0.0.0.0`, `localhost` is fine with SSH tunneling.

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that you have configured public key in your MySQL Workbench settings.

You need to use your private key in MySQL Workbench settings, and then install the corresponding public key to remote host user's `.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistake in the question. I was actually using the private key there. The corresponding public key is there in the server. It is working correctly in the winscp. But one factor is that, I have created the key-pair by puttygen and used a passphrase there. So, during winscp it asks for it. But it is not the same here.

Comment: Then the problem could be the key file format. MySQL Workbench might expect OpenSSH style private key files, and if you are using Putty-style key files, it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable sshd port forwarding in your ssh server. Make sure you have `AllowTcpForwarding yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file and that ssh service was restarted. You can test this with:

- OpenSSH: `ssh -v -L 3306:localhost:3306 user@VM`
- PuTTY: `plink -v -L 3306:localhost:3306 user@VM`

And `bind-address` should be `localhost` if you have the web application on the same VM.

Comment: MySQL Workbench creates the port forwarding when one uses the configuration in question. There is no need to do it separately.

Comment: It was for testing. Just read the entire answer, please. I am referring to the part "You can test this with: "

Comment: IMHO, OpenSSH and PuTTY gives better debug details than paramiko. https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko

Comment: paramiko is the python library used internally by MySQL Workbench